# Read a csv-file value by value with Scanner, useDelimiter(";") not working

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to read a CSV file value by value using `Scanner.useDelimiter(";")`.
However `Scanner.nextLine()` still returns the whole line instead of a single Value.

The CSV-file looks like this:

```
0.00034;0.1;0.3;0.6;1,00E-13
```

My code:

```
Scanner iStream = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.cvs);
iStream.useDelimiter(";");
String[] test = new String[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test[i] = iStream.nextLine();
}
```

Result:

```
"0.00034;0.1;0.3;0.6;1,00E-13"
```

Expected Result:

```
"0.00034", "0.1", "0.3", "0.6", "1,00E-13"
```

Is this possible, or should I use `String.split()`?
Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm really suggesting [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), It's great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this problem is ready-made for a parsing library such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), `nextLine` doesnt account for delimiter patterns. Use `next` instead

```
test[i] = iStream.next();
```

Comment: I knew, that it was something really simple. I'll look into opencsv, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Scanner documentation:

```
public String next()

Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. 
A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.
```

This literally answers your question. However, I am not sure about `next`'s behaviour at the start and end becuase it has to be "preceded and followed" by the delimiter. Maybe someone can fill in on this?

You could add extra characters to your delimiter, like `\n`etc.